# Windows 10 hotkey for activate window by hovering over it with the mouse setting

Tags: windows, windows-10, settings, keyboard-shortcuts

The setting "Activate Window by hovering over it with the mouse" is convenient but sometimes annoying so I would like to disable it through keyboard whenever I want. However, I cannot find any solution to do that.

Does anyone know how can I do that? Using an application is fine too as long as it does the job, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure there is shortcut for "Activate Window by hovering over it with the mouse".

You said external app is also ok how about [X-Mouse Controls](https://joelpurra.com/projects/X-Mouse_Controls/)

Comment: Yup that solves the problem thanks.